# Why are the energy levels in the organic materials called HOMO and LUMO instead of Valence and Conduction band in inorganic materials?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I am studing the OLED screen technology! for that, I need a proper explanation about this topic.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! Please be more specific, try to look around for a solution yourself, tell us what you found and what it is that is still unclear.

Comment: HOMO/LUMO come from chemistry (bonds in molecules, even complex ones). Valence/conduction bands come from solid state physics of extended crystal states. The "organic" part of Organic LEDs are complex molecules, so are talked about with chemistry terms.

Comment: The terms Valence and Conduction bands are actually used more often than required. They are justified as for organic molecules are suitable for devices like the OLEDs you've mentioned. Thus there must be (via redox processes, hopping) a sort of *effective* band structure. The situation would be similar to that of amorphous or perhaps microcrystalline inorganic semiconductor, but an even smaller scale...

Comment: ... For ideal virtually infinite conjugated polymers you can also think of a "in-chain" band. But at the end, organics semiconductors are molecular in nature, and as such certainly have their own molecular orbitals.  Applying semiconductor concepts can certainly give the feeling of understanding a device functioning, but is in my opinion not representative of the physics undergoing. The latter is certainly difficult to approach. But ignoring the molecular nature cannot be the way.